# Simple programming practice (using modulus op)

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators

First question, I'm trying to do a practice where I am asked to return true if the given non-negative number is a multiple of 3 or 5, but not both. Examples are;

old35(3) → true

old35(10) → true

old35(15) → false

*So 3 would be true, as it's a multiple of 3, but I can't currently make my code work for all instances. Code below;*

```
public boolean old35(int n) {
     if ((35 % n == 3) || (35 % n == 5))
        return true;
     return false;
}
```

How could I edit this to fit the criteria of what the practice is telling me to do?
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will throw a detailed explanation. First, you use the remainder sign to check the condition where remainder is zero;

```
n % 3 == 0
```

and

```
n % 5 == 0
```

Then for a one to one translation for your conditions, put them together as:

```
((n % 3 == 0) || (n % 5 == 0)) // Multiple of 3 or 5

!((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)) // But not both
```

Add (and) them together;

```
public static boolean old35(int n) {
  return(((n % 3 == 0) || (n % 5 == 0)) && !((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)));
}
```

But simply, what you are doing is the XOR (^) operation, the following code is valid and simple:

```
public static boolean old35(int n) {
  return((n % 3 == 0) ^ (n % 5 == 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical XOR of the conditions. Basically you can do `C1 ^ C2`.
Edit: To check if multiple of 3 you must check `n % 3 == 0`, the same for multiple of 5.

Comment: I've heard it is bad practice to use the XOR operator, would there be any other way whilst still keeping the code nicely?

Comment: you can check if the number is divisible by 3 and not 5 OR divisible by 5 and not 3